# Android: how to answer call automatically?

Tags: android, hook, action, call, headset

I am trying to make that my phone automatically answer calls, but looks like google remove permissions for this way:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
m.setAccessible(true);
ITelephony telephonyService;
telephonyService = (ITelephony)m.invoke(tm);
telephonyService.silenceRinger();
telephonyService.answerRingingCall();
```

So i find other way here:
http://code.google.com/p/auto-answer/source/browse/trunk/src/com/everysoft/autoanswer/AutoAnswerIntentService.java

```
// Simulate a press of the headset button to pick up the call
Intent buttonDown = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);             
buttonDown.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
context.sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonDown, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");

// froyo and beyond trigger on buttonUp instead of buttonDown
Intent buttonUp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);               
buttonUp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
context.sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonUp, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
```

But it doesn't work too.
What I miss?

Comment: Did you add the proper [permissions to your Manifest?](http://code.google.com/p/auto-answer/source/browse/trunk/AndroidManifest.xml)

Comment: Yes of course I did, I even load those app on my phone but it doesn't work too.

Comment: That code is working for me!

Answer (score -1):

Change the following

```
context.sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonDown, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
```

to

```
context.sendBroadcast(buttonDown);.
```

same with buttonUp . Because `sendOrderedBroadcast()` can be aborted by other receiver.